# if(!empty($_POST['delete'])) query issue

Tags: php

I have used this html code

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="button" id="delete" name="delete" value="delete">
</form>
```

and the following code for deleting the data from table:

```
$usr = $_SESSION["user"];
if(empty($_POST['delete'])) {
        $query="delete from roombook where Email='$usr'";
        $res= mysqli_query($con,$query);
        if($res->num_rows>0) {
             echo"<script>alert('Deleted');</script>";
         }
}else {
    echo"<script>alert('delete failed');</script>"; 
}
} else {
    echo"<script>alert('not found');</script>"; 
}
```

But it  always show me the else statement output only that is: delete failed

Comment: There are multiple issues with this. `$query` is just a variable, it doesn't do anything. `delete *` is invalid SQL. `$usr` should be bound, current usage would likely open you to SQL injections. Your `if` also isn't checking that the delete worked at all, just that the form submitted.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST['delete'])` yield?

Comment: How is this form even submitted since you don't have any submit-button? Through JS?

Comment: @user3783243 Or even just `var_dump($_POST);`.

Comment: it's unclear how this would even do anything - as mentioned there appears to be no way to submit the form, the query is never executed, and even if it was, the script would output "yes" without actually checking if it succeeded or not.

Comment: `name="dlt"` is useless..forms don't need a name, only the fields within them do

Comment: `$usr` is still not defined in your code...where do you expect to get the value for this from?

Comment: 1. How is the form submitted 2. `delete * from` must be `delete from` 3. bind, don't concatenate, `where Email=?` 4. The `else` should be on `if($res->num_rows>0)`... possibly put an `else `on the form submitted value check and say `submission failed` or something to distinguish the error.

Comment: @NayanJadhav `delete from` deletes the row from the DB. You can't delete a single column.

Comment: Use error reporting on the query execution http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php Also did you start your session?

Comment: @user3783243 yes i  started the session at line 2 of code...

Comment: Problem solved... actually it was <input type="button"> whereas it should have been type="submit"

Comment: yes you can't submit a form with type="button". Another possible problem here, unless you have written this higher up the page already, is that it will **always** display the "not found" message when you load the page, even _before_ you submit the form. The way round this is to wrap all of your above code inside `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // …
}`, so that it only runs when the request is a "POST". (When you load a page first in the browser, the HTTP "GET" method is used.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form

```
 <input type="button" id="delete" name="delete" value="delete">
```

Should be the following code:

```
 <input type="submit" id="delete" name="delete" value="delete">
```